# silverstripe 3.0: how to add different tinymce configurations per user group

Tags: silverstripe

there's no information about how to have user groups use different tinymce configurations in the docs for silverstripe 3.0 (yet), and although you can find *some* information in the docs for 2.4, it doesn't really help either: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/rich-text-editing#security-groups-with-their-own-editor-configuration

so how do you apply a different tinymce configuration for some user group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most of what's required is to be found in this forum thread: http://www.silverstripe.org/general-questions/show/11434

so, basically you have to define your new tinymce configuration like so (inside your `_config.php`):

```
$cfg = HtmlEditorConfig::get('authors');
$cfg->setOptions(array(
    'friendly_name' => 'Restricted',
    'priority' => 1, //required, see forum thread
    'theme_advanced_blockformats' => 'p,h3'
));
```

this configuration will be picked up by the cms an is then available inside the 'Security' section (see on on top of the 'Permissions' tab for a selected group).

that's already nice, but you'll notice that some important features are missing in the newly configured tinymce instances then, most notably the buttons for 'insert image' and 'insert link'. that's because lots of the default configuration for the standard 'cms' config aren't actually HtmlEditorConfig 'defaults' but instead defined inside /framework/admin/_config.php.

simplest solution to keep the 'default' behaviour i found is to add the following right before the preceding code block:

```
HtmlEditorConfig::$configs['authors'] = clone HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms');
```

this will make sure you got all the basic functionality available in your new 'Restricted' configuration.